# Why am I getting memory location values after printing prime numbers of a particular range?

Tags: c

I am solving [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) problem:

> Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help
>   him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given
>   numbers!
>
> **Input**
>
> The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line
>   (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1
>   <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> **Output**
>
> For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n,
>   one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Input:
> 2
> 1 10
> 3 5
>
> Output:
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 7
>
> 3
> 5
> ```

I am getting memory location values after I get prime numbers in the output.
Can you explain about how I can terminate after getting the final output.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int t, i, m[10], n[10], j, k, l, isPrime;
// t is test case, m[] and n[] are the lower and upper value of the range of prime numbers
// isPrime is to check the condition True or False.
j = 0;
scanf(" %d \n", &t);

for(i=0; i<t; i++)
{
  scanf("%d%d",&m[i],&n[i]);
}

while(j<=i)
{
  for(k = m[j]; k<= n[j]; k++)
  { isPrime = 0;
    for(l = 2; l<= (k/2); l++){
        if(k%l == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime==0 && n[j]!= 1)
        printf(" %d \n", k);
  }
  j++;
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can terminate by returning from `main`. What are "memory location values"?

Comment: I am getting random 7 digit values like 2687615, which goes on. I am guessing that these values are the address values.

Comment: Don't guess, that just confuses things. Show an example of input and output.

Comment: When I input - 2  (new line)3 7  (new line)4 9 , My output is something like 3 (new line) 5 (new line) 7 (new line) 5 (new line) 7 (new line) 2686751 (new line) 2686759 (new line) 2686777 , and it goes on without terminating.

Comment: Hint: Those are prime numbers. I assume the 2687615 from your previous comment was just made up?

Comment: SPOJ does not necessarily supply any input for `getch()` after the stated input data, and it probably won't compile it anyway. It uses gcc.

Comment: The value 2687615 was for a different input.

Comment: I got the answer. The problem was with the logic, the while loop should have been while(j<i) instead of while(j<=i). I thank you all for your help. Also I had the remove the getch()

Answer (score 0):

You are using getch() which will stop the program until you press any key right after the execution of all your program. remove getch(), compile and run the .exe from the source folder file after closing the IDE.

Comment: I removed getch() and compiled again after closing the IDE but the problem still persists.

Comment: While you open the .exe file it must not give output (in the case you are eliminating getch() )

Comment: I understand the problem is with the for loop

Comment: when you enter a character a-zA-Z it creates problem. Don't put in those. Input only 0-9 numbers your program is correct.  it terminates if we provide correct input.

Comment: I will keep it in mind, about not using single characters as variables. I tried to again execute the .exe application which is located in my workspace/bin/Debug directory but the problem exists if I use more than 2 test cases. I am using Code::Blocks as my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I executed the code, without getch() and it worked fine!